# getting errorStatusCode: -12884 for AVPlayerItem in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, avplayer

I'm able to play recorded content in my iOS using AVPlayer.
But if play the video for more than longer duration like 1 hour I get below error for AVPlayerItemErrorLogEvent

errorStatusCode: -12884 errorDomain: CoreMediaErrorDomain errorComment: Media File not received

I googled and even checked apple document could not find any reference for the same.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritemerrorlogevent/1387875-errorstatuscode?language=objc

Thanks